# Тридевятое царство

Tags: этимология

В сказках часто фигурирует "тридевятое царство, тридесятое государство". Что имеется в виду? Расстояние от, так сказать, исходной точки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из Википедии:
Тридевятое царство — «иная, далекая, чужая, волшебная» земля (страна).

Выражение «Тридевятое царство, тридесятое государство» очень часто встречается в русских народных сказках как синоним выражения «очень далеко». Происхождение выражения связано с тем, что в древней Руси словом «земля» называли, в частности, территорию, подчиненную одному правителю (например, Ростово-Суздальская земля — территория, подчиненная князьям, жившим в городах Ростове и Суздале). Таким образом, герой, который отправляется «за тридевять земель», должен в своих странствиях пересечь соответствующее количество достаточно больших территорий и находящихся между ними государственных границ.

Естественным фоном для действия русских мифов служило привычное место обитания (поле, лес). В качестве противопоставления предусматривалась «Иная», чужая, странная земля: Тридевятое царство, Тридесятое государство… Изначально это были степи, пустыни, а также часто леса и непроходимые болота и другие сказочные препятствия (к примеру, реки с огнём) и т. п.

Само происхождение термина следующее: в старину считали по тройкам, отсюда тридевять (три раза по девять) — двадцать семь, тридесять — тридцать.

Answer (score 0):

Тридевятый - 27-й, тридесятый - 30-й, как вы понимаете. 
А имеется в виду то же самое, что при указании типа "седьмой дом от угла".
Двадцать шесть "царств" пройдёшь - в двадцать седьмое попадёшь.
~~~~
А вики-то как всегда. Масса информации, кроме нужной.

Answer (score 0):

А я и такую версию читал ещё (не в ИНЕТЕ): за тридевять ЗЕМЕЛЬ - если под  словом земля понимать диаметр земного шара, то до Луны их как раз 27. Вот и получается: за тридевять земель - то есть, на Луне. Кстати, Конёк-горбунок там и побывал. Вроде он Иванушку туда прокатил.
А в ВИКИ немало и полезного. Всё ж там не всё  с потолка взято

Answer (score 0):

Окружность Земли ~40 тыс.км. Расстояние от Земли до Луны ~360 тыс.км (при максимальном приближении спутника). Выходит 9 окружностей Земли или 9 Земель. Когда Луна находится в дальней точке, расстояние ~400 тыс.км. Это уже 10 окружностей или 10 Земель. Вот и получается, что "тридевятое царство, тридесятое государство" это и есть Луна. А расстояние до неё не фиксированное а изменяется от 9 Земель до 10 Земель.

Comment: Это вы серьезно? А как могли древние померить?